# Rails and postgresql not dialoguing properly on record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The following record creation is failing as the data is being misinterpreted by Postgresql

```
SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "gruppomerceologicos" ("nome", "reparto_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["nome", "Salumeria"], ["reparto_id", 1], ["created_at", "2020-03-13 09:24:15.529470"], ["updated_at", "2020-03-13 09:24:15.529470"]]
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

PG::NotNullViolation - ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Salumeria, 2020-03-13 09:24:15.52947, 2020-03-13 09:24:15.52947, 1).
```

The row creation is in effect incorrect as PostgreSQL is attempting to handle a record with a `null`value for `id`

The controller is standard

```
@gruppomerceologico = Gruppomerceologico.new(gruppomerceologico_params)
authorize @gruppomerceologico
@gruppomerceologico.save
respond_with(@gruppomerceologico)
```

The rails debugger does however show that it is attempting to handle a record without an ID at point where error is occuring

```
@gruppomerceologico 
#<Gruppomerceologico id: nil, nome: "Salumeria", created_at: "2020-03-13 08:24:15", updated_at: "2020-03-13 08:24:15", reparto_id: 1>
```

Postgre has the following data structure

```
         Table "public.gruppomerceologicos"
   Column   |            Type             | Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id         | integer                     | not null
 nome       | character varying           |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone | not null
 reparto_id | integer                     |

 Indexes:
    "gruppomerceologicos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_gruppomerceologicos_on_reparto_id" btree (reparto_id) Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_d8a087054a" FOREIGN KEY (reparto_id) REFERENCES repartos(id) Referenced by:
    TABLE "materiagrezzas" CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_2b6ca167a0" FOREIGN KEY (gruppomerceologico_id) REFERENCES gruppomerceologicos(id)
```

Normally Postgre knows it is creating a new record and will thus assign the sequential ID and create the record. But this is not happening.  Where is the gap between rails and Postgresql?

The initial migration:

```
class CreateGruppomerceologicos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :gruppomerceologicos do |t|
      t.string :nome

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

followed by an update in migration

```
class AddRepartoToGruppomerceologicos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :gruppomerceologicos, :reparto, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

**Update**
Double checking with a development server, the `\d` query for the table returns something completely different:

```
      Table "public.gruppomerceologicos"

   Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                     Default
------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('gruppomerceologicos_id_seq'::regclass)
 nome       | character varying           |           |          |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
```

where the `nextval` is obviously in proper play.  The two databases were somehow out of synch.  As suggested below by @sebastianPalma `select nextval('gruppomerceologicos_id_seq'::regclass);` will directly reveal the discrepancy.

Comment: How does the migration for creating the `gruppomerceologicos` table look like?

Comment: Is that the full output for the table inspection? It seems it lacks a few columns, what's the default value of the id column?

Comment: I updated the question to add that info and refresh the `\d`info...  Oh my... my localhost database is not returning the default column as is the development server.  Is that a possible explanation?

Comment: Probably that explains the problem, try just `select nextval('gruppomerceologicos_id_seq'::regclass);` in both environments.

Comment: Bingo!  on localhost `ERROR:  relation "gruppomerceologicos_id_seq"` does not exist, whereas is does on the development server.  I'll edit the question so that this case may be of use (although that doesn' explain how this discrepancy came about in the first place!)

Comment: Nice one! Are you getting the same error if you recreate the database and run the migrations? As in fresh project cloning set up?

Comment: Sorry, had not seen last part of comment.  I managed to reproduce the behaviour.  It stems from recovering a copy of the database from another server, then running migrations locally.  The new tables locally just don't have the default values.